# javafx separator not visible in hbox

Tags: javafx, separator, hbox

I can't get my separator to show up on my form. It is currently in an `HBox` that is in a `VBox`:

```
Separator separator1 = new Separator();
hbox5.getChildren().add(separator1);
```

The separator is supposed to be under the `clear` and `calculate` `button` and above the `converted temperature` line.

[image]

Comment: Why is the separator in it's own hbox?

Comment: So it will take its own row in the vbox, however, I am not committed to anything if there is a better way.

Comment: A box puts each of its children in their own row. This might be the problem, or maybe not. I don't have a system that can compile Java with me now.

Comment: You were correct. I took it out of the ```HBox``` and put it straight into the ```VBox``` and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning how this works. I appreciate your help. :)